# Rerender the entire component if a specific prop changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this Component:

```
<Animatable.Text animation='pulse' style={styles.toggle}>Items: {props.items}</Animatable.Text>
```

Whenever I get an update for props.items, the Component re-renders the change, the value, but the animation doesn't re-appear.

How do I make the animation re-appear? Cause the props to run again? basically completely re-rendering the component causing it reload the animation prop?

[Note that the animation only runs on load, not state change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6E2fF.gif)

Full component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View , TextInput, Button, Alert, StyleSheet } from 'react-
native'
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable'

export default class Adder extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        text: '',
        items: this.props.items
    }
}

render() {
    const { add, clear, items } = this.props
 return (
     <View style={{paddingTop: 50}}>
      <TextInput placeholder='Buy...' autoCorrect={false} value={this.state.text} onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})} style={{ backgroundColor: '#ededed', height: 60, textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: 10 }} />
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around'}}>    
          <Button
          title='Add Item' 
          onPress={() => {
          this.state.text != '' ? add(this.state.text) : Alert.alert('Enter Groceries')
          this.setState({text: ''})
          }}
          />  
        <Animatable.Text animation='pulse' style={styles.toggle}>Items: {this.state.items}</Animatable.Text>
        <Button title='Mark All' onPress={() => clear()} />
      </View>
    </View>
 )
}
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
toggle: {
    width: 100,
    backgroundColor: '#333',
    borderRadius: 3,
    padding: 5,
    fontSize: 14,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
  }
})
```

Comment: add `key` to your tag.

Comment: change state of your component . it will re-render automatically.

Comment: When I get a prop that is a state, It doesn't count as a state change?
@MukulSharma

Comment: You are only using Animated library in react-native right? No other extenal library?

Comment: @D-reaper That's correct, the value itself does work, but I want the animation to re-appear

Comment: Can you show the full react component? just so that we know how you are doing the animation

Comment: @EGK then you need to change the title of your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Animatable doesn't make the animation reappear when the state changes, you probably want to call the animation imperatively. One way of doing this is to use a ref on the Animatable text and call it on componentWillUpdate. So something like the following:

```js
// this gets triggered when you get a new state
componentWillUpdate() {
  // pulsate for 800 ms
  this.animatedText.pulse(800);
}


//.. render method
<Animatable.Text 
    animation='pulse' style={styles.toggle} 
    ref={(text) => { this.animatedText = text; }}>
        Items: {this.state.items}
</Animatable.Text>
```

Comment: I was told that refs are a bad thing and that you should avoid them, care to explain why? and if so, is there a way to do the same thing without using refs?